# Move every first row down to the second row

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following sample text:

```
a b c
x_y_
d e f
x_y_
g h i
x_y_
k l m
x_y_
```

I need it to be formatted as follows:

```
x_y_ a b c
x_y_ d e f
x_y_ g h i
x_y_ k l m
```

Using sed, awk or something else in bash, how do we accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `awk` and put two conditions, if `NR % 2 == 1` to print odd rows and `NR % 2 == 0` to print even rows

Comment: Noted - I will add what I tried next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another awk:

```
$ awk 'NR%2==0{print $0,p}{p=$0}' file
```

Output:

```
x_y_ a b c
x_y_ d e f
x_y_ g h i
x_y_ k l m
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR%2==0 {          # on every even numbered record
    print $0,p     # output current record and previous
}{
    p=$0           # buffer record for next round
}' file
```

**Update**:

In case of odd number of records (mostly due to the peer pressure :), you need to deal with the left-over `x y z`:

```
$ awk 'NR%2==0{print $0,p}{p=$0}END{if(NR%2)print}' file
```

Output:

```
...
x_y_ g h i
x_y_ k l m
x y z
```

Comment: That's true, but as they are printed in pairs, I assumed even number of records (read: can't happen on my spectrum). Fine, I'll fix it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 You've been mentioned in the update. ;D Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/g' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

a short pipeline:

```
tac file | paste -d ' ' - - | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR%2{s=$0; next} {print $0, s}' file
x_y_ a b c
x_y_ d e f
x_y_ g h i
x_y_ k l m
```

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, tested and created with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){printf("%s\n",$i OFS $(i-1))}}' Input_file
```

OR(with `print`):

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){print $i,$(i-1)}}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** By checking if a line number is completely divided by 2 then print previous and current lines values. It also checks if total number of lines are ODD in Input_file then it prints last remaining line too(by checking a flag(variable)'s status).

```
awk 'prev && FNR%2==0{print  $0 OFS prev;prev="";next} {prev=$0} END{if(prev){print prev}}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
x_y_ a b c
x_y_ d e f
x_y_ g h i
x_y_ k l m
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1~2{h;d};G;s/\n/ /' file
```

Save odd line numbered lines in the hold space and append them to even numbered lines and replace the newline with a space.

Another variation:

```
sed -n 'h;n;G;s/\n/ /p' file
```

There are many more ways to achieve this, as can be seen by answers above.

How about this:

```
parallel -N2 echo "{2} {1}" :::: file
```

See [here](https://zenodo.org/record/1146014) for parallel.